# Hive throwing error while using beeline or java jdbc code

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I am trying to use `JDBC` code to connect to my server but it is giving following error.

I checked and found that the `SessionState` class is member of `hive-exec-0.14.0.jar`. I could see this jar in hive classpath. When I checked this class in apache documents, the method setUserIpAddress is not available. Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
2016-01-13 03:15:18,443 INFO  [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-24]: thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:OpenSession(232)) - Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V6 
2016-01-13 03:15:18,444 ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-24]: thrift.ProcessFunction (ProcessFunction.java:process(41)) - Internal error processing OpenSession java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.setUserIpAddress(Ljava/lang/String;)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.<init>(HiveSessionImpl.java:112)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImplwithUGI.<init>(HiveSessionImplwithUGI.java:47)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.openSession(SessionManager.java:260)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.openSessionWithImpersonation(CLIService.java:175)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getSessionHandle(ThriftCLIService.java:322)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.OpenSession(ThriftCLIService.java:235)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1253)
         at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1238)
         at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
         at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
         at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
         at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:206)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `SessionState.setUserIpAddress` is new to hive 1.0

In [r0.13.1](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.13.1/api/ql/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.html) this method did not yet exist,

in [r1.0.1](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.0.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/session/SessionState.html#setUserIpAddress(java.lang.String)) it's there.

Please upgrade your hive-exec to version > 1.0.1 to make this work.